# how to get multiple values from single text box and store it in array and also store it in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

Can I use php to get multiple values from one input text box and store it in array?
I want to read multi integers from the user and store it in array
For example, I add one input text and one submit:

Comment: The methods will depend upon how the text is entered i.e. 12, 23, 34 or 12 23 34 or 1,234 2,345 3,456 or 12.0, 23.1, 34.2

Comment: Do you want the user to add an integer, then press submit, then another, press submit until there are multiple integers that can be sent, or do you want the user to enter a comma separated list of integers?

Comment: `Can I use php to read values from one input text box and store it in array?` I'm sure you could try

Comment: yes adriancarriger

Comment: yes  adriancarriger i want  both techniques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in this way.

Make an form in HTML having an input which should take comma seperated integer values like this:

```
<form action="url" method="POST">
    <input id="dataInput" type="text" name="data" value="12,34,56">
    <button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now on submitting the form, you should receive the data in PHP, and you can use php's [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) method like this:

```
<?php

$data = $_POST['data'];
$data_arr = explode(',', $data); // <----- explode the string here from commas
// Now you can store these values into the database
```

So the output for the `$data_arr` would be:

```
$data_arr = array(
    0 => '12',
    1 => '34',
    2 => '56'
);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: the values 12 , 34 ,56 are store in data base separately in each cell

Comment: That totally depends upon you, you can save them in separated columns or you can save them as `json format` in a single column. That totally depends upon the use case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)() function
Then
[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)() function to make sure you get the NUMERIC values

```
<?php

// Assuming your method is POST 
// and assuming the delimiter (entered by user) is UNITED as a COMMA "," 
$_POST['input_name'] = explode(",", $_POST['input_name']);
$_POST['input_name'] = array_walk($_POST['input_name'], 'floatval');

?>
```

Comment: but how to stor it in database each value in each cell